# How to add a caption to a long tabularray table read by csvreader?

Tags: captions, longtable, tabularray, csvsimple

I am reading data for a supplementary info from different CSV files using the csvsimple package.
To display things nicely, I have written my own csvstyle, as all the CSV files have the same format.
For certain tables, the data is too long and requires multiple pages. This works easily by changing the csvstyle to use `long tabularray` instead of `tabularray`.
A problem occurs now, when I want to add a caption to this long table: if I wrap the `\csvreader` and the `\caption` in e.g. `\begin{table}`, the table does not do any page breaks anymore; if I use e.g. `\begin{longtable}` instead of `\begin{table}`, compilation does not work anymore, each row gets another header row, and things like that, depending on the wrapper.

What is the correct procedure to add a caption here?

Below, a minimum reproducible example with the \begin{table}, that does not do page breaks.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf}, font=small, justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty = true, multi-part-units=single]{siunitx} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% For including csv as tables
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}

\NewTableCommand\toprule{\hline[0.08em]}
\NewTableCommand\midrule{\hline[0.05em]\vspace{1pt}}
\NewTableCommand\bottomrule{\hline[0.08em]}

\csvstyle{MyStyleLong}{
no head,
before reading=\centering\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center,table-format=3.3,table-auto-round},
long tabularray={
colspec={c@{}S[table-format=3.4]S[table-format=1.2]l},
row{1} = {guard},
column{4} = {cmd=\ch}
},
table head=\toprule\empty & m/z & {Relative Intensity} & Annotation
\\\midrule,
late after line=\\,
late after first line=\\\hline\endhead,
late after last line=,
table foot=\bottomrule,
late after line=\\,
}
 
\begin{filecontents*}[]{test-file-long.csv}
  mz, Intensity, annotation \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH \\
  12.13, 1901.0, CH2OO- + H+\\
  1.20, 56.01, CH3OH
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

% the first empty is for using S as first column
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Test}
\csvreader[MyStyleLong, filter expr={test{\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{1}}}]{test-file-long.csv}{}{\empty & \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `longtblr` environment provides the key `caption` as an option.
As far as I saw, `csvsimple` does not provide any access to these options.
However, one can redefine the template's default text in such a way:

```latex
\begin{document}

\blindtext

% the first empty is for using S as first column
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}{Test}
\csvreader[MyStyleLong, filter expr={test{\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{1}}}]{test-file-long.csv}{}{\empty & \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii }

\end{document}
```